# How to set up Netbeans, Mercurial and BitBucket with SSH

Tags: version-control, netbeans, mercurial, ssh, bitbucket

I set up Mercurial (actually TortoiseHg) to work so that Netbeans could interact with [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org). I set it up with HTTPS, but now I'm trying to use SSH instead. I'm not having much success. Here are the steps I took:

First, I opened PuTTYgen and generated an SSH2-RSA key. I wrote my email - the same one I used to register on BB, I don't know if that matters - as the Key comment. Anyway, I uploaded the public key to BitBucket and it accepted it.

Then I created a private key and added it with pageant, as [this page](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+SSH+to+Access+your+Bitbucket+Repository;jsessionid=E69923A8E6B8E35AA9CF203C34465E76) instructs. After that I made a command from the command line to verify it worked:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo
```

It worked - cloned the entire repo to my computer. But then I went over to Netbeans and right-clicked on my project and went to **Mercurial > Properties...**. I filled out the box like this:

```
default-push: ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo
default-pull: ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo
username: My Name <my@email.com>
```

I tried to push/pull my repo, but it didn't do *anything*. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup the SSH link in the hgrc file for the repository or the one that is used by Netbeans.

Details can be seen here, how it can be setup: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqHgSSH

Answer (score 2):

You can setup your repo as https. I already tried and it works.

```
default-push: https://hg@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo
default-pull: https://hg@bitbucket.org/myaccount/myrepo
username: My Name <my@email.com>
```